# Hide silver color of toolTip jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tooltip

Why I see that silver color of tooltip? And how to hide or remove it?

I'm using jquery-1.10.2 version.

Picture how now is: 
I want to hide that silver color around my yellow box.
Here is how it looks.
[image]

My css code:

```
    .ui-tooltip {
    background: #666;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    opacity: 1;
}
.ui-tooltip-content {
    position: relative;
    padding: 1em;
      background-color: #ffff00;
}
.ui-tooltip-content::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
}
.right .ui-tooltip-content::after {
    top: 18px;
    left: -10px;
    border-color: transparent #666;
    border-width: 10px 10px 10px 0;
}
.left .ui-tooltip-content::after {
    top: 18px;
    right: -10px;
    border-color: transparent #666;
    border-width: 10px 0 10px 10px;
}
.top .ui-tooltip-content::after {
    bottom: -10px;
    left: 72px;
    border-color: #666 transparent;
    border-width: 10px 10px 0;    
}
.bottom .ui-tooltip-content::after {
    top: -10px;
    left: 72px;
    border-color: #666 transparent;
    border-width: 0 10px 10px;
}
```

Code where i using tooltip:

```
   <img title="Tooltip on left" style="border: 1px solid black;" id="@(Model.Id)@(pegiPicture)" src="@Url.Content("~/Images/Pegi/" + pegiPicture + ".png")" width="@(pegiInfo)" height="@(pegiInfo)"/>
              <script>
                  $(document).ready(function() {
                      var position = { my: 'left center', at: 'right+10 center' };
                      position.collision = 'none';
                      $('img[title]').tooltip();
                      $('img[value="right"]').trigger('change');
                      $('img[title]').tooltip('option', 'position', position);
                      $('img[title]').tooltip('option', 'tooltipClass', 'right');
                  });

              </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I found solution. I looked in my jquery-ui.css and looked where color changed. So here is color for all controls:

```
.ui-widget-content {
border: 1px solid #dddddd;
/*background: #eeeeee url(images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_100_eeeeee_1x100.png) 50% top repeat-x;*/
color: #333333;
```

}

And here is this silver color. So I just can remove somehow that class from  my tooltip and thats will be done.

[image]

And here in jquery js I just can remove classes:

```
        .addClass("ui-tooltip  ui-corner-all  " +//ui-widget ui-widget-content
            ( this.options.tooltipClass || "" ) );
```